# Positions of "of which"

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

I am not sure how to use *of which* here. I do know I could use *whose*, I would just like to understand this structure more.

Each bag contains a number of bank notes (bills).

And now:

> Select the bag the sum of notes of which is 1000.

or

> Select the bag of which the sum of notes is 1000.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use *whose* unless it referred to a person.

Comment: Most people would, though; it falutes a little too high for conversation, but not for precise description.

Comment: _In which_ works much better in the second sentence, since it's a bag. And the first sentence is completely ungrammatical. "Of which" is not an idiom; it's produced by grammatical rules, and it can work with any preposition if it's there to start with..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking one relative pronoun and one participle to do just a little bit too much work here. If you ignore the *Select* temporarily and turn what's left around, the problem is evident:

> This bag's sum of notes is 1000.

This is awkward because the *sum* is not directly a property of the bag but of the notes. It is the notes which are a property of the bag.

What you want is a graceful way to designate the indirect relationship. One solution would be to introduce a second participle phrase:

> Select the bag **in which** the sum **of the notes** is 1000.

A briefer way would be to use *sum* as a verb instead of a noun:

> Select the bag whose notes **sum** to 1000.

Comment: Thanks. However as I mentioned, I am interested in the usage of "of which". I do know I could say it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is really suitable, and nor is *whose*, because the bag is not the sum of anything other than the materials it’s made of. 
What you have to do is refer not to the bag but its contents. That means that all these are possible sentences:

> Select the bag the sum of whose contents is 1000 notes.
>
> Select the bag the sum of the contents of which is 1000 notes.
>
> Select the bag the sum of which the contents is 1000 notes.

The first is the most satisfactory one. If you really want to use *of which*, use the one that places *of which* after *contents*.

If you really wanted to speak of the sum of the bag, the possibilities would be:

> Select the bag whose sum is 1000 notes.
>
> Select the bag the sum of which is 1000 notes.
>
> Select the bag of which the sum is 1000 notes.

The first is preferable, but I emphasise that referring to the sum of a bag, rather than its contents, sounds strange.

Comment: Not sure if I get your comment - the bag contains money (bills) and you ask for the sum of the money it contains.

Comment: @Pietros. Exactly. You ask for the sum of money the bag contains (the contents), not for the sum of the bag itself.

Comment: So it cannot be said with the "notes"? (meaning it is its content). And can I not say "The bag whose sum of its content"?

Comment: I hope that the edit I have just made to my answer will make it a little clearer.

Comment: Well I did not make it clear, I guess. By sum I mean the actual sum of the notes value (2 notes with (of?) 50 pounds value = sum is 100 pounds).

Comment: @pietros: Notes never sum to 1000, they may sum to £1000. In addition, this is a peculiar use of *sum*, as well as Barrie's point that a bag is not the sum of anything. I think there is a reasonable question about *of which* as against *whose*, but to ask it you will have to edit out a lot of extra material.

Answer (score 0):

The bag which: *Select the bag which contains a total of $1000 in notes*

Perhaps this works, but I am not totally sure of the grammar

The notes which: *Select the bag containing only notes, the sum of which amounts to $1000*